# SONAR coding rule for junit assertion

Tags: junit, mocking, sonarqube

It is great that SONAR can detect junit test without an assertion, but in practice mocking technology may be used during junit test, f.e. EasyMock or Mockito. Then question raises from here: some of the test cases only need verification of mocking object method call, and no assertion is needed. Is there a way to tell SONAR to accept mocking utility verification method as a valid assertion besides junit assertion?

B.R.

Comment: Nope nothing out of the box. You might have to write your own custom PMD rule for this